# Sign In with TweetSharp by using ID and Password

Tags: c#, api, twitter, tweetsharp

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService("CONSUMER KEY", "CONSUMER SECRET");
service.AuthenticateWith("TOKEN KEY", "TOKEN SECRET");

var retweets = service.ListRetweetsByMe();
```

So I can use this script to get all retweets but from which user?
I think I should first authorize with correct credentials. So how can I do it?
User should put his/her ID and PW to sign in.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use oauth:

```
TwitterClientInfo client = new TwitterClientInfo();
        client.ConsumerKey = "ConsumerKey";
        client.ConsumerSecret = "ConsumerSecret";
        twitterService = new TwitterService(client);
        requestToken = twitterService.GetRequestToken();
        Uri urlAuth = twitterService.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
```

you can send the user to that url with a webbrowser control or how you want...well and then you need to receive the pin with a textbox or something...i answer thinking that you are talking about a desktop app.